# How do I use the fonts used in Ubuntu in Lubuntu?

Tags: fonts, lubuntu

I had installed Ubuntu for years on my laptop, but on new machine I decided to install Lubuntu because I have been unsatisfied with Unity. Everything looks cool, but fonts now look really ugly with annoying rainbow effect.

So, anybody knows how to make fonts look as beautiful as in original Ubuntu? Maybe install extra package or something.

Comment: What do you mean by beautiful? Can you provide us a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Go into the Lubuntu theme preferences and onto the dont tab and fiddle with the RGB, BGR settings for your font smoothing and anti-aliasing and apply each one to see if it fixes your fonts on your particular screen...

Comment: i checked those seetings, currently they fully match ones on my old machine